# Algorithm for computing the $n$-th root of any polynomial with detached coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Can somebody already acquainted with the subject explain in detail how to extract the $n$-th root of a polynomial using the method of detached coefficients? I have tried the whole day to understand books on the subject and they always end up being vague when the order of the root becomes high.

I think I have understood how to extract the square root of any polynomial and the concept of detached coefficients but I still have problems to understand what to do with the so-called columns on the left when the order of the root is large (3+) after finding the first two coefficients in the root-polynomial... I have no idea what to do recursively in the columns because all of the books I read usually explain the first steps to find the first or second coefficient of the root polynomial, and then pretty much say "etc.", but the "etc." is not precise enough for me. The books are old too, and the wording does not allow me to extrapolate and be autonomous...

I ask this here in case somebody knows, since it has been taught neither to me nor to anyone I know. These seem to be "ancient" maths and not used a lot nowadays...

Ok as requested I am providing an example of said book. The goal is to extract a cube root of order $3$ of $a^6-6a^5+21a^4-44a^3+63a^2-54a+27$
[image]

In this picture I understand the first three lines.

The $1\quad1\quad1$ makes sense to me, this is just the first coefficient repeated three times as prescribed by the usual method.

Then, the two lines that follow are just the algorithm as described

After that, I don't understand what I should do next, once I have the first three lines and found the two coefficients $1$ and $-2$.

Why $1$ in the fourth line, second column ? Why is it then changed into $-2$ ? Why are there two occurences of $-2$ in this column in the following lines instead of just one before proceeding to using the next coefficient $3$ instead?

Comment: maybe you should give an example or two. Seems to be synthetic division, or an alternative to that

Comment: @WillJagy I would like to but they are difficult to depict using only LateX. I will upload a picture as an example I don't quite get

Comment: What seems to be missing is the part about taking a square root. I can show you how I do that, not quick but effective

Comment: @WillJagy I have understood the method for $n=2$. I think it is easier for me since there are only two columns to use but it gets trickier after that (for $n>2$)

Comment: the part I cannot tell: are you using this only when you are assured that there is an exact root, meaning you are factoring the polynomial?

Comment: @WillJagy This method should work either way. If there is an exact root,  the algorithm ends in the rightmost column with only zeros and the exact root is given. The algorithm should work if there is no exact root, in which case one should get an infinite series. What does **not** work though, is extracting a nth root when the highest order term is of order not divisible by n. (i.e. it won't work if I want to extract a cube root of $x^2+x$, but it will work if I want a square root of $x^2+x$). For the beginning though I usually make sure there is an exact root so that I can check easily

Comment: Alright. If I got $(x^2 - 2x + 3)^3$ and it was a little off because someone changed the constant term $27$ to $29,$ I would next try  $(x^2 - 2x + 3 + \frac{A}{x})^3,$ find the best $A,$ (possibly $0$) then $(x^2 - 2x + 3 + \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2})^3,$ and so on

Comment: Got thrown by the cube root... to get to 29, first nonzero is at $(x^2 - 2 x +  3 + \frac{A}{x^4})$

Answer (score 2):

First step in discussing factoring your sextic: gcd with derivative

$$  \left(   x^{6}  - 6 x^{5}  + 21 x^{4}  - 44 x^{3}  + 63 x^{2}  - 54 x  + 27 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 5 x^{4}  + 14 x^{3}  - 22 x^{2}  + 21 x  - 9 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{6}  - 6 x^{5}  + 21 x^{4}  - 44 x^{3}  + 63 x^{2}  - 54 x  + 27 \right)  =  \left(   x^{5}  - 5 x^{4}  + 14 x^{3}  - 22 x^{2}  + 21 x  - 9 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) } +  \left(  2 x^{4}  - 8 x^{3}  + 20 x^{2}  - 24 x  + 18 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  - 5 x^{4}  + 14 x^{3}  - 22 x^{2}  + 21 x  - 9 \right)  =  \left(  2 x^{4}  - 8 x^{3}  + 20 x^{2}  - 24 x  + 18 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  -  \left(   x  - 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{6}  - 6 x^{5}  + 21 x^{4}  - 44 x^{3}  + 63 x^{2}  - 54 x  + 27 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  - 12 x  + 9 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  - 5 x^{4}  + 14 x^{3}  - 22 x^{2}  + 21 x  - 9 \right)  =  \left(   x  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  - 12 x  + 9 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  - 12 x  + 9 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{6}  - 6 x^{5}  + 21 x^{4}  - 44 x^{3}  + 63 x^{2}  - 54 x  + 27 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{2 } \right)  -  \left(   x^{5}  - 5 x^{4}  + 14 x^{3}  - 22 x^{2}  + 21 x  - 9 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  - 12 x  + 9 \right)  $$

=========================================================

Pretty impressive. Let's try gcd with second derivative

$$  \left(   x^{6}  - 6 x^{5}  + 21 x^{4}  - 44 x^{3}  + 63 x^{2}  - 54 x  + 27 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 20 x^{3}  + 42 x^{2}  - 44 x  + 21 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{6}  - 6 x^{5}  + 21 x^{4}  - 44 x^{3}  + 63 x^{2}  - 54 x  + 27 \right)  =  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 20 x^{3}  + 42 x^{2}  - 44 x  + 21 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 23 }{ 25 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 64 x^{2}  - 128 x  + 192 }{ 25 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 20 x^{3}  + 42 x^{2}  - 44 x  + 21 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 64 x^{2}  - 128 x  + 192 }{ 25 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 125 x^{2}  - 250 x  + 175 }{ 64 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 23 }{ 25 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 23 }{ 25 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 125 x^{2}  - 250 x  + 175 }{ 64 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 25 x^{4}  - 100 x^{3}  + 250 x^{2}  - 300 x  + 225 }{ 64 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 125 x^{2}  - 250 x  + 175 }{ 64 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  - 12 x  + 9 \right)  \left( \frac{ 25}{64 } \right)  -  \left(  5 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 7 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 23 }{ 64 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{6}  - 6 x^{5}  + 21 x^{4}  - 44 x^{3}  + 63 x^{2}  - 54 x  + 27 \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  - 4 x^{3}  + 10 x^{2}  - 12 x  + 9 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 20 x^{3}  + 42 x^{2}  - 44 x  + 21 \right)  =  \left(  5 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 7 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{6}  - 6 x^{5}  + 21 x^{4}  - 44 x^{3}  + 63 x^{2}  - 54 x  + 27 \right)  \left( \frac{ 25}{64 } \right)  -  \left(  5 x^{4}  - 20 x^{3}  + 42 x^{2}  - 44 x  + 21 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  - 10 x  + 23 }{ 64 }  \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right)  $$

Comment: Ok I understand how it works, just not why the first gcd is necessary (that with the first derivative)

Comment: @Evariste just showing how to find if a polynomial has any repeat factors, not assuming that I know anything. Once I got a nontrivial result for $\gcd(f,f')$ it is then reasonable to check either $\gcd(f,f'')$ or $\gcd(f',f'').$ Note that this would not help in the experiment I mentioned , change the constant term 27 to 29, so that the thing is not longer a cube of a polynomial